# UTC-N to Local Time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, utc

Using joda, how do you format a UTC+/-n time, to "wall time" to be displayed to the user:

From (UTC+/-n):

`2015-05-15T03:28:49.523-04:00`

To (EST) Wall:

`2015-05-14 23:22:44`

**Update (1)**

Please consider the following code. We need to use timestamp
for writes to and from the DB in UTC. With that in mind:

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);
LocalDateTime utcDate = new LocalDateTime();
DateTimeZone utcTZ = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("ETC/UTC"));
DateTimeZone localTZ = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Montreal"));      
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");        
fmt.withZone(localTZ);

DateTime localDateTime = utcDate.toDateTime(localTZ);
DateTime utcDateTime = localDateTime.toDateTime(utcTZ);

Timestamp u = new Timestamp(utcDateTime.getMillis());

System.out.println("UTC Time: " + u);

LocalDateTime date = new LocalDateTime(u);
DateTime srcDateTime = date.toDateTime(utcTZ);
DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.toDateTime(localTZ);

System.out.println("UTC+/- Time: " + dstDateTime.toString());

DateTime dateTimeInTargetTimezone = dstDateTime.withZone(localTZ);
System.out.println("Wall Time: " + dateTimeInTargetTimezone.toString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Now, when extracting the UTC time from the DB in a Timestamp object, we need
to display the time to the end user in a "Wall/Funeral Time", whatever you want to call it, in their TZ.

Output

```
UTC Time: 2015-05-15 20:03:47.561 "Good"
UTC+/- Time: 2015-05-15T20:03:47.561-04:00 "Good"
Wall Time: 2015-05-15 20:03:47 "No! No! No! Danger! We'll be late!"
```

What in the name! Do I have to do to get `dstDateTime` to equal the time I see on my wall (ie, 2015-05-15 4:03:47).

**Update (2)**

Got rid of Timestamp:

```
DateTimeZone utcTZ = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("ETC/UTC"));
DateTimeZone localTZ = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Montreal"));
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime utcDate = new LocalDateTime(utcTZ);
DateTime utcDateTime = utcDate.toDateTime(utcTZ);       

System.out.println("UTC Time: " + utcDateTime);

DateTime dstDateTime = utcDateTime.toDateTime(localTZ);

System.out.println("Unformated Wall Time: " + dstDateTime);
System.out.println("Wall Time: " + dstDateTime.toString(fmt));
```

Output

```
UTC Time: 2015-05-20T14:09:28.469Z
Unformated Wall Time: 2015-05-20T10:09:28.469-04:00
Wall Time: 2015-05-20 10:09:28
```

Everything looks perfect however, when I try to right the UTZ date to the DB,
I need to convert to Timestamp (ie, new Timestamp(o.getOrderDate().getMillis())), and it obviously rights the local time to the DB, and not the UTC Zulu time that I need.

Thanks in Advance,

Nick.

Comment: I would also like to put the "wall time" <code>2015-05-14 23:22:44</code> into a Timestamp object.

Comment: You comments about the conversions in your update don't make sense. First off, you're printing "UTC time" and the output of java.sql.Timestamp.toString, but that output is not in UTC, it's in your local timezone. Which would be set by TimeZone.setDefault, which you're not calling (although you are calling DateTimeZone.setDefault, hence Joda-Time has a different default timezone to java.util.Date). Set both defaults to UTC and the outputs should make more sense.

Comment: Hello Araqnid! Thank you so much it makes some much more send now. Please look at my update above.

Answer (score 0):

@Nick

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but you can try this:

```
    //sample input
    String timestamp = "2015-05-15T03:28:49.523-04:00";

    //format to parse
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeF = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    //parse to local date time
    LocalDateTime dateTime = dateTimeF.parseLocalDateTime(timestamp).minusHours(4);
    //output here minus 4 hours
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

You can improve your implementation from my sample code above and make the offset hours more dynamic but so far this code provides the result as you mentioned in your example.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thank you for your response. My questions is how to get actual TZ date time from UTC+/-n (ie, UTC-4, UTC+5). I have the following time "2015-05-15T03:28:49.523-04:00" and would like to format it to "2015-05-14 23:22:44" to display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the DateTime.withZone method to change the timezone:

```
@Test
public void change_timezone() {
    String input = "2015-05-15T03:28:49.523-04:00";
    DateTimeZone targetTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(input);
    DateTime dateTimeInTargetTimezone = dateTime.withZone(targetTimeZone);
    assertThat(dateTimeInTargetTimezone.toString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), 
               equalTo("2015-05-15 08:28:49"));
}
```

Comment: Hello Araqnid, Thank you for your response. I have been doing this however getting the wrong time. Can you please see my update above.